# C++ Crash on get statement?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I've run into an... interesting problem. I've found that my program is crashing on a standard get statement. For context, I'm overriding the `onEnter` function (from Cocos2dx framework) to swap an image after modifications in a further scene.

My modification looks as follows:

icons is `map< ClassA, CCSprite* >`

`current` is of `ClassA`

```
void onEnter(){
    <parent class>::onEnter();
    CCSprite* sprite = icons[current];
    if (sprite){
        CCNode* parent = sprite->getParent(); //Crashes Here
        if (parent){...}
    }
}
```

From Cocos2d-x:

```
CCNode* getParent(){
    return m_pParent;
}
```

Note: I don't have issues with calling this function anywhere else but here.

Also:

1. Yes, icons exists
2. Yes, current exists
3. Yes, sprite exists
4. current is not a pointer

If it helps I'm using QNX Momentics IDE.

EDIT:: Here's an image

[image]

Comment: My guess is either `sprite` is `nullptr` and is therefore dereferencing a null pointer, or since you are relatively certain it isn't, it may have been `delete`'d but not set to `nullptr`, so it contains garbage. Or that index in the `icons` array was never set properly, so it just has whatever nonsense was at that memory location when it was initialized.

Comment: @Cyber: since the value of icons and it's contents aren't modified between the scenes, it couldn't have been deleted. I also checked for null. I also set all the values beforehand (in the constructor) so I somehow doubt the nonsense part as well. I'll look to see if it's a valid CCSprite though?

Comment: Remember that C++ has no memory safety. It's possible some other code overwrote part of `icons` so that `sprite` is pointing somewhere wrong.

Comment: If this in a Debug or Release build?  If it's a Release build (or if optimizations are enabled), then the debugger may be lying to you about where the crash is actually occurring.  What does the disassembly look like at the crash location?  The disassembly never lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it wasn't a valid CCSprite. In between the declaration and calling of onEnter the release pool that cocos2dx uses marked it for delete. It seems in some cases during the constructor, the CCSprite wasn't added to a parent and it wasn't marked for retention. Thus, it was deleted but some garbage remained. Thanks [Cyber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296458/cyber).